# Sharing session data between Rails and Node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

The main question is: Can I read Rails session data in Node?

More details:

I have a project that is written in Ruby on Rails. It works but I want to add to it and eventually replace it using NodeJS. Both are running on the same server, just on different ports.

As of now RoR will serve up all the HTML files (and continue handeling the existing functionality) and then I'll connect to the Node server via AJAX. Node will just dish up JSON for the time being.

The problem is, how can I work with session variables between the two? More specifically, can I get to RoRs session variables in Node? Mostly I just need to know which user is logged in.

If it matters, I am running Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, and Node 0.8.17.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried exactly same stuff, myself, but, we did something similar but with Sinatra and Java.

I wouldn't comment about your approach on application design, but, in case you don't mind using Memcached session store in your rails application, yes it is possible. Configuring Memcached with Ruby app is explained on [Heroku Doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache)

In Node application you can use Memcached Client like [3rd-Eden](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) and access session variable from memcache

You would have to explicitly pass session id generated by rails to Node.

Comment: So basically just store the session variables in a DB and then pass the session ID between RoR and Node? Am I understanding this correctly? I suppose I should ask, if RoRs authenticates a user, is there a better way to make sure Node is working with that user?

Comment: No need to store session id in DB. I said use Memcached as session store. Session id of the user will be available in your rails app, you can pass that to node as a query parameter while making Ajax request, right? I cannot comment about authentication bit.

Comment: ^ This is bad practice because then anyone with the session id can pretend to be the user they stole it from.

Comment: Yes, but if someone 'stole' it, then they can anyway use it. Rest does not matter.